# Access denied error when trying to install an extension in team foundation (2015 Update 3) on premises

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to install an extension by using the web access in team foundation (2015 Update 3) on premises, but it always give me an Access Denied error (either with a custom extension or one downloaded from the marketplace).

[Image error from web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ2Vk.jpg)

Same happens when I try to install it using tfx-cli:

```
C:\>tfx extension install --auth-type basic --service-url http://servername:8080/tfs/collection1--extension-id "extension1" --publisher pubb
2016-09-14T20:50:35.411Z : loader.load
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.3.30
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
2016-09-14T20:50:35.882Z : cache.getItem

> Username: domainame\asdffasdsa
> Password:
2016-09-14T20:50:43.054Z : extensioninfo.getExtInfo
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z : Error: Failed Request: Internal Server Error(500) - Access denied.
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at processResponse (C:\Users\asdffasdsa.domainame\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tfx-cli\node_modules\vso-node-api\RestClient.js:59:18)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at C:\Users\asdffasdsa.domainame\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tfx-cli\node_modules\vso-node-api\RestClient.js:162:13
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at callback (C:\Users\asdffasdsa.domainame\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tfx-cli\node_modules\vso-node-api\HttpClient.js:141:17)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at handleResult (C:\Users\asdffasdsa.domainame\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tfx-cli\node_modules\vso-node-api\HttpClient.js:157:17)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\asdffasdsa.domainame\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tfx-cli\node_modules\vso-node-api\HttpClient.js:168:17)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
2016-09-14T20:50:48.712Z :     at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
Error: Failed Request: Internal Server Error(500) - Access denied.
```

any idea of what could be the problem or how to diagnose it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Edit collection-level information permission?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you are lacking of the permission.Try to add your user account to **Build  Administrator Group** then try the install again.

You can also use [tfssecurity command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) to give your account the related permission.

---

Please take a look at this issue in GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/141 .Seems it's related to nodejs version.

Comment: Still the same error. I've added the user to the "Project collection build administrators" and I'm also a member of the "Project collection administrators" and the "Team Foundation Administrators" groups, and local administrator in the server.

Comment: Please take a look at this issue in GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/141 .Seems it's related to nodejs version.